# NullReferenceException running Silverlight Unit Test

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I'm trying to get a Silverlight 4 unit test to work (using the framework from Microsoft that's installed with the Silverlight Toolkit) and get a NullReferenceException checking the Text property of a TextBlock.  I'm sure I'm missing something in getting the xaml page to load / initialise.  Here's the code:

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests 
{
    private MainPage _myPage;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void PreparePage()
    {
        _myPage = new MainPage();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TitleIsInInitialState()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(_myPage.myTextBlock.Text, "myText");
    }
}
```

I then run the html page that refers to my Silverlight unit test project.  What am I missing?

Thanks,
Krip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `MainPage()` constructor throwing an exception?

I've found that the Silverlight test runner rather helpfully swallows exceptions thrown in methods with the `[TestInitialize]` attribute.  Try moving the line `_myPage = new MainPage();` to your test method.

Comment: You are a genius!  That was it!  I was missing References to third party controls.  Didn't realize that I need the same references in the unit tests project.  As soon as I moved the newup code I found the real problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Krip: Thanks for the feedback.  Of course, we would have avoided the problem entirely if only `[TestInitialize]` methods didn't swallow exceptions.  I was a bit annoyed when I found that this happened.  It certainly wasn't what I expected.  I don't know of any other test frameworks that do this.